# Ruby on Rails Blog Producing Duplicate Comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, blogs

I recently followed the ruby on rails tutorial on how to create a simple blog with comments, and everything is working just fine, except if you add more than one comment to a post it returns 4 comments to the page, two of the first, and two of the second comment (ill add a picture). I do not understand why it is doing this, only two records are in the database, and I am using a for each loop to return the comments in the database associated with the correct post ID.

The code and images are below:

```
    <% @article.omments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    Comment Author:
    <a href="http://<%= comment.website %>" target = "_blank" ><%= comment.commenter %></br></br></a>
    Comment Date: <%= comment.created_at %>
  </p>

  <p>
    Comment: 
    <%= comment.body %>
  </p>
  <p>
  <%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>

<% end %>
```

Here it is with one comment:
[image: Just One]

Here is the second case:
[image: Two Comments]

I hope someone can help me, because I am at a loss. Thank you!

Comment: You only included the code that displays comments. Why don't you post the code that actually creates comments? Not sure how you've set it up, but it's probably going to be the `new` method of your `comments_controller.rb`.

Comment: The tutorial didn't use a new method, they used a create method. Is the new method vital? Is the absence of one possibly causing the problem?

Comment: `new` was just a guess based on the common practice but let's not get hung up on trivia. How about you post the code rather than getting ahead of yourself on things that don't matter?

Comment: I fixed the issue,  and I wasn't getting ahead of myself because new was used in other parts of the tutorial and I thought a mistake was made.